# Restringir los tipos de archivo en un input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

¿Es posible en un input de tipo file restringir los formatos que este puede aceptar al momento de realizar la selección de archivos?

Comment: Hola Yolany! ¿Qué has investigado al respecto?¿Ya has intentado implementarlo de alguna manera?

Comment: ¿Has investigado algo? [Esta es la mejor explicación que conozco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23706177/5587982), porque trata el problema en toda su amplitud: establecer filtros del lado del cliente es posible, pero no es 100% seguro ni compatible. Un filtrado del lado del servidor sería entonces lo más recomendable, aunque establezcas filtros del lado del cliente con `accept`.

Comment: Ya intentaste con atributo accept del input file, ejemplo si quieres que solo te seleccione imagen puedes ocupar <input type="file" accept="image/*">

Comment: Justamente estoy haciendo uso de accept, el hecho es que si el cliente por algún motivo cambia la personalización que se le muestra predeterminada, aún así acepta el archivo, me recomendaron el uso de filter para este caso, he investigado pero no lo he logrado comprender, me podrian dar una idea de como hacerlo porfavor?

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con que *cambia la personalización que se le muestra predeterminada*? Por favor tómate el tiempo de exponer tu problema con claridad editando la pregunta, no podemos adivinar lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: @A.Cedano leí detenidamente el enlace, y encontré la respuesta a mi pregunta, lo que deseaba saber era si es posible restringir el tipo de archivo desde el selector nativo del sistema operativo. Muchas Gracias!

Comment: No es posible restringir desde lo que llamas el *selector nativo del sistema operativo*. Es el navegador el que lanza la selección de archivos y por tanto es desde el navegador donde puedes restringir con `accept`. Si lo quieres restringir en el mismo selector, para que por ejemplo te aparezcan en gris ciertos tipos de archivos que no aceptarías para selección, tendrías que programar arduamente tu propio selector, o modificar el del sistema operativo mismo para ese contexto, poniéndolo en relación con el navegador. Algo harto trabajoso (si fuera posible) y casi inútil...

Comment: Anteriormente realice las restricciones desde el lado del servidor, porque es la mejor practica, pero cuando presente mi proyecto me sugirieron usar filter, para evitarle perdida de tiempo al usuario. Muchas gracias por la aportación!

Comment: Las pérdidas del tiempo al usuario se evitan fácilmente con `accept`. De ese modo trabajará bien con un usuario *normal*. Ahora bien, si hablamos de un *hacker*  que va a intentar enviar diabluras al servidor desde tu formulario, por más controles que hagas desde el cliente serán a veces insuficientes. En ese caso, tienes que pararle los pies estableciendo un buen sistema de filtrado en el servidor. Conclusión: puedes filtrar con  `accept`, pero conviene controlar en el servidor, entre otras cosas porque un usuario mal intencionado puede mandar archivos saltando los controles en el cliente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con jquery puedes hacer esto:

```js
$("#archivo").on("change", (e) => {
  const archivo = $(e.target)[0].files[0];
  let nombArchivo = archivo.name;
  var extension = nombArchivo.split(".").slice(-1);
      extension = extension[0];
  let extensiones = ["jpg", "png", "jpeg"];
 
  if(extensiones.indexOf(extension) === -1){
    alert("Extensión NO permitida");
  }else{
    alert("Extensión permitida");
  }
  
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="file" name="archivo" id="archivo" />
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

La idea es obtener el nombre del archivo y allí también obtener la extensión y luego compararlo con un array donde tienes todas las extensiones permitidas.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aportación.!

Answer (score 1):

con el atributo accept puedes filtrar de lado del cliente, pero tambien debes validar en el servidor.

```html
<form>
  <input type="file" name="pic" id="pic" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg" />
</form>
```